# Gitlab CI variables returns empty string?

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, adonis.js

It's been 2 days since one of my project' build starts failing on Gitlab CI. The main error was `E_MISSING_APP_KEY` and when I check another variable just by echoing `$HOST` and `$PORT` from my `.gitlab-ci.yml` config, like this

```
tests:
  script:
    - echo "${HOST} ${PORT}"
    - node -e "console.log(process.env.HOST, process.env.PORT)"
    - node_modules/.bin/nyc node ace test -t 0
```

I got nothing.

[image: initial error]

The build was failed because it can't read my environment variable that I set on its CI Settings.

[image: my CI variable setting]

Anyone experiencing same issue? & how to solve this?

---

Update:

I'm trying to create new project with only containing `.gitlab-ci.yml` file [here](https://gitlab.com/feryardiant/echo-env) and it's seems working just fine

[image: result on new dummy project]

But why the world it's still failing on my [main project](https://gitlab.com/feryardiant/saf)?

[image: kee failing]

Comment: Have you tried any of the steps outlined at the "More details" link?

Comment: The "More details" link is actually built-in "exception message" from Adonis.js frameworks & the errors has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. You said the `E_MISSING_APP_KEY`  error is thrown, and that "more details" link provides info about the `E_MISSING_APP_KEY` error. How is that not relevant?

Comment: Edited, apologize about that..

Comment: I see, so you've entered the variables into the CI's settings but adonis can't seem to access the APP_KEY. Is it accessible from `process.env`?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see on my first image. `echo "${HOST} ${PORT}"` also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved by delete all of my variables I've had & set them back from the CI Setting. And the build pipeline is running without any errors. *(except the actual testing is still failed, lol)*

[image]

Honestly, I'm still wondering why this could happened? and hopefully no one will experiencing same kind of issue like me here..

Answer (score 40):

For anyone else having a similar problem:

check your variable, if it is protected your branch has to be protected as well or remove the protected option on your variable

Comment: Dude, thank you. This was a key point that I missed and fixed my issue immediately.

Comment: My branch is protected, I unprotected the variables and still got this issue fixed.

Comment: Bingo Boom Shakalaka!!

Comment: Works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are running the job on tag creation, you have to protect the tag**. To do that automatically, you can give it a pattern to Gitlab in order to protect it. If you think anyone should be able to create a tag, then better to unmark the protected option for the variables.

From [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_tags.html):

> To protect a tag, you must have at least the Maintainer role.
>
> 1. Go to the project’s <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Repository</kbd>.
> 2. From the Tag dropdown list, select the tag you want to protect or
>
> type and select Create wildcard. In the screenshot below, we chose to
> protect all tags matching v*
>
> [image: Protected tags page]

You can protect only giving maintainers permission to create a tag pattern, for instance.

> From the <kbd>Allowed to create</kbd> dropdown list, select users with permission
> to create matching tags, and select Protect